# Как правильно организовать частые запросы к серверу?

Tags: android, long-poll, fcm

Приложение каждые 15сек обращается к стороннему API для обновления инфо. Инфо представляет собой ~100 сущностей с внутренними данными, которые могут меняться в произвольные промежутки времени. То есть за 15сек могут поменяться данные в 79 или 100 сущностях, а могут ни в одной.

Почитал что на частое создание соединений с сервером уходить много ресурсов, как у сервера так и у клиента. И что longPooling в лице FCM решает эту проблему, экономя трафик и процессорное время.

Не совсем понимаю действительно ли подойдет здесть вариант с FCM.

1. Нужен ли здесь LongPooling? Или просто дергать сервер каждые 15сек?
2. Если да, то как это работает?Я подписываюсь из аккаунта FCM на определенные данные от сервера и FCM будет мне присылать данные по каждой обновивщейся сущности отдельно или будет в некоторой период времени скидывать мне все обновившиеся сущности за это период.

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант использования сокетов!